# histogram in data warehouse

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse

I got a ton of samples in the following format:

```
 <timestamp> <dim1> <dim2> <dim3> 324
 <timestamp> <dim1> <dim2> <dim3> 3565
 <timestamp> <dim1> <dim2> <dim3> 122
 <timestamp> <dim1> <dim2> <dim3> 2333
```

324, 3565, ... are the measurements, and I would like to store these in a data warehouse.

The measurement will be rounded to the nearest hundred (300, 3600, 100, 2300).

How can I store this and quickly be able to create a histogram of the facts?

One (bad) way is to have a column in the fact table for each "bucket" (ie 100, 200, 300, ...), and then use SUM() on each column to build up the histogram.  The drawbacks are obvious: the fact table will be huge and non-flexible (limited range of samples)

Anyone got any clever ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to discretize somehow. One way -- providing that your bucket ranges do not change frequently -- is to add a table with ranges (`dimBucket`) and assign a bucket key to each value during the ETL. If value ranges ever change, the whole fact table has to be re-calculated to assign new `BucketKeys`. So, something like this -- note that `ValueRange` is a string like `'100-199', '200-299', ...`

```
SELECT
  ValueRange
, sum(SaleAmount)  AS SaleValue
, count(1)         AS Transactions
from factSale  AS f
JOIN dimBucket AS b ON b.BucketKey = f.BucketKey
GROUP BY ValueRange;
```

[image]

I find it hard to work with generic `<dim>, <dim>, <dim>` so I have used my own example.

The other way is not to think about it on the DW level, but to use an analytic package. Almost every analytic/data-mining package offers several types of discretization. Try [**Weka**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/), it's open source and quite good;  [**R**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) is very popular too.